# Creating colors with UIColor

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uicolor

I am trying to create the below color in Xcode, but cannot seem to get it to match?

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0 green:47 blue:135 alpha:1]];
```

Is there something I am doing wrong, or should change the color does not match what I expect?

Comment: Reminder - as you type in a question, SO shows you related questions that may already answer your question. A quick look at those related questions would have shown you the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

`setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:15/255.0f green:47/255.0f blue:135/255.f alpha:1]];`

[UIColor expects the colors to be a value between 0 and 1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html), so you have to divide those values by 255.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use as RGB value then you can define it as like below:

```
#define RGB(r,g,b) [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1]
```

Comment: You really should put parentheses in there: `#define RGB(r,g,b) [UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0 green:(g)/255.0 blue:(b)/255.0 alpha:1]`. Without those parentheses, you will have issues with code like: `UIColor *c = RGB(x + 4, y - 10, z - t);`.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. I was in a hurry..;)